# How to access outer property in #each scope with itemController

Tags: ember.js

I have some code like below.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({ });
App.Router.map(function() { this.route('users', {path: '/'}); });

App.UsersRoute= Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [{name:'John'}, {name:'Taro'}];
  },
});

App.UsersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  greeting: 'hello',
});

App.UserController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  greeting: 'good morning',
});

Em.TEMPLATES['users'] = Em.Handlebars.compile(
  '{{#each user in controller itemController="user"}}' +
     '<p>{{greeting}}&nbsp;{{user.name}}</p>' +
  '{{/each}}'
);
```

This code display these content.

```
good morning John
good morning Taro
```

But I want to display like below.

```
hello John
hello Taro
```

I confirmed that removing itemController option displays above.
But I want to use itemController option for some reason.

How can I access UsersController's greeting property in #each scope with itemController?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2614

Using parentController achives my goal.

```
Em.TEMPLATES['users'] = Em.Handlebars.compile(
  '{{#each user in controller itemController="user"}}' +
     '<p>{{parentController.greeting}}&nbsp;{{user.name}}</p>' +
  '{{/each}}'
);
```